# div wrapped with link not appearing as clickable in IE 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <div style="float:left;">
        Test
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        testing
    </div>
</a>
```

The link works correctly (clicking anywhere in the div navigates to the link) but in IE7 the div doesn't appear to be clickable. When hovering over the div the cursor does not change to a hand.

The hover works as excepted in IE8, Firefox, chrome

My guess is that there is the usual ugly IE hack for this :-(

Comment: did you make it `display:block?`. Also, I don't think this is valid HTML. I think only HTML5 allows this.

Comment: DOCTYPE is ??  or you using Quirksmode?

Comment: DOCTYPE XHTML 1.0 Strict. User agent style sheet has made div element "display:block"

Comment: I have not set "display:block" anywhere

Comment: Always remember to validate your code. It's a much better way to get your website looking as you want it than hacking together CSS styles. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @anothershrubery, although it's not valid HTML4 - it has always worked, and it is valid HTML5 (it's easier to use something that already works instead of implementing 'href' on all elements cross-browser!) - so if you want to use it going forward you'll have to get used to invalid error messages while sites transition between 4 & 5.. get used to it ;)

Comment: OK thanks, I feel a little better about my crappy code now :-) . Im trying to implement a sort of tile ui component. Ive seen a good implementation of this on the gowalla.com home page. Looks like they use the height attribute of the surrounding <a> try help achieve this affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a {
  display: block;
  background: #eee; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

the link still works, even without the pointer changing, however IE7 does like it better if hasLayout is set to to true (`overflow:hidden;` which also contains the floats in other browsers), and then just tell it to have the right cursor.. it needs help ;)

Comment: This worked for me. a.myClass:hover {
 cursor:hand;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

This should work unless you've got some extra markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cd4PK/

However this is bad markup. You should not have block elements (divs) within inline elements (a). Try using a span?

Comment: I have updated my original post to reproduce the issue in IE7. Note multiple divs within <a>

Answer (score 0):

`href` cannot be `......` or empty

**edit:**

try:

```
a
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```